# Can a Poco WebSocket constructor be passed a timeout?

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

Looking at the Poco documentation, I see that some `Socket` constructors can take a `Timespan` as timeout but I'd like to know if it's possible to do it with `WebSocket` or am I stuck with the default of one minute?

Essentially, my problem is that if networking services become unavailable while connecting, it takes a full minute (the default timeout value) before the constructor returns or throws a `Timeout` exception. Is there no way around that?

I've tried a gazillion things already, all pretty harebrained. I thought I had my way in by keeping a reference to the `HTTPClientSession` used to instantiate the `WebSocket` and reaching for `HTTPClientSession::socket()` and manipulating that but unfortunately, that socket is not actually a valid socket. The `HTTPClientSession` here is just used for temporary information while creating the WebSocket, it seems.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set timeout in constructor.
I use this code:

```
TimeSpan timespan(10, 0);
WebSocket ws(request, response);
ws.setReceiveTimeout(timespan);
ws.setSendTimeout(timespan);
```

It works for me when reading from or writing to the WebSocket but I don't know if it is taken into account when connecting. I used it with a TimeSpan of 600 seconds to avoid too much disconnect/reconnect from clients.